# Javascript multiple api fetches (youtube)

Tags: javascript, json, api, object, youtube

I'm trying to make a json object of the views per video for a youtube user.

First I am making an api call to get all the video ids from a specific channel, these are pushed to an empty array. Then I loop through all the video ids to make multiple API calls for every video to get the data about the views.

Right now every video has it's own API call and I can't seem to find a way to combine all the data from all the calls in a single object.

I am sure this is not the way of doing this, that's why I hope you guys could recommend me a better way of tackling this problem.

Thanks!

```
var channelId = 'UCO1cgjhGzsSYb1rsB4bFe4Q'
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=' + apiKey + '&channelId=' + channelId + '&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20'

fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(data) {
        var videoIds = []
        for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
            videoIds.push(data.items[i].id.videoId)
        }
        return videoIds
    }).then(function(ids) {
        var urls = []
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            urls.push('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=' + ids[i] + '&key=' + apiKey)
        }
        return urls
    }).then(function(urls) {
            for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                fetch(urls[i]).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                })
            }
```

---

### update

I managed to fix this by using another fetch url and the d3.json function.

```
var search = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=' + apiKey + '&channelId=' + channelId + '&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=5'

var videoIds = []

fetch(search).then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
        videoIds.push(data.items[i].id.videoId)
    }

    return fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" +videoIds + "&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&key=" + apiKey);

}).then(function(response) {
        d3.json(response.url, function(error, data) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                    console.log(data)
```

Comment: How things going? Did my answer help?

Comment: @Matt Yes thanks, your answer did help. Just that the object being returned does not include the statistics of each individual video. Now I'm trying all kinds of things to extract the statistics.viewCount from these fetches into a combined object. Would you have any tips on this?

Comment: According to the API Reference for `video`, the you should be able to access the viewCount through JSON using the following dot notation `videoObj.statistics.viewCount`. Here is the link to the current documentation as of Dec 2017 [YouTube Video API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)

Comment: After looking at the request above, maybe try removing the `part=statistics` from the request. My guess it that the request should return the full `video` object in which you could then follow the direction from the comment listed above.

Comment: Did everything work out? If so, please vote/confirm answer. If not, I'm happy to help get you past this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own promise that is used as a wrapper to wait for all of the parallel promises to return, once they all have returned successfully, you can `resolve` the promise, confirming its successful completion or your can `reject` the promise and provide an error response if something went wrong.

Note that the real work is done inside the function `getChannelVideos(channelId, config)`...more precisely, inside the Promise body:

```
var channelId = 'UCO1cgjhGzsSYb1rsB4bFe4Q'

 + '&channelId='
const baseUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3';
let config = {
  apiKey: 'yourKeyHere',
  part: 'snippet,id',
  order: 'date',
  maxResults: 20
}

function queryArgs(config) {
  let query = '';
  config.apiKey ? query += '?key=' + config.apiKey : throw { err: 'You must provided an API KEY' };
  config.part ? query += '&part=' + config.part : query;
  config.order ? query += '&order=' + config.order : query;
  config.maxResults ? query += '&maxResults=' + config.maxResults : query;
  return query;
}

function getChannelVideos(channelId, config) {
 let URL = baseUrl + '/search' + queryArgs(config) + '&channelId=' + channelId;
 // We wrap everything we need to do in a Custom Promise, and return it for a .then(res => { // Success Handler }, err => { // Error Handler })
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // videos to store data from each video request, videoPromises to wait on
    let videos = [];
    let videoPromises = [];
    // Make the Channel Request, followed by a request for each of its videos ( Callback hell)
    fetch(URL)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then(
        data => {
            // Declare vars outside map for improved memory management
            let currentVideoId;
            let currentRequestUrl;
            // iterate of the 'data.items' creating a new array of promises (.map(handler) returns a new array of whatever is returned from the handler)
            videoPromises = data.items.map(item => {
              currentVideoId = item.id.videoId;
              currentRequestUrl = baseUrl + '/videos?part=statistics&id=' + currentVideoId + '&key=' + config.apiKey;
              return fetch(currentRequest)
                       .then(
                         res => {
                           // Push the Video Response to the videos array (You may want to select something more specific like 'res.data', but this depends on what data you want
                           videos.push(res);
                         }, 
                         err => {
                           console.log('Ut-oh - a Video request failed', err);
                         });
            });
        });
      // Wait for ALL the promises to succeed
      Promise.all(videoPromises).then(
        success => {
          console.log('It\'s all good! Everything was retrieved successfully!');
          resolve({
            status: 200,
            data: {
              videos : videos
            }
          });
        },
        err => {
          reject({ 
            status: 500,
            error: err, 
            message: 'Whomp Whomp Whomp! Something didn\'t work, but the data has what did!', 
            data: videos 
          });
        })
  });
}

// NOW CALL IT
getChannelVideos(channelId, config).then(
  res => {
    // here are the videos
    console.log('videos[]', res.data.videos);
  },
  err => {
    console.log('Darn, maybe next time', err);
  });
```

You should also see a performance boost as there are fewer loops and less on the call stack. The `Array.map(handler)` is a pretty awesome higher ordered function the JavaScript community encourages use of. Happy Coding!

Comment: I usually use the `lodash` library, so my map function may need a little tweeking, but you should get the gist. I also assumed that the `fetch(url)` function returns a promise based on your use of the `.then()`

Answer (score 0):

To kill the `Promise hell` welcome to

> ES2017 `async/await` syntax

Change your whole code to something like this

```
async function foo() {
    var channelId = 'UCO1cgjhGzsSYb1rsB4bFe4Q'
    var url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${apiKey}&channelId=${channelId}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20`

    var resp = await fetch(url)
    var data = await resp.json()

    var videoIds = []
    for (var item of data.items)
        videoIds.push(item.id.videoId);

    var urls = []
    for (var id of videoIds)
        urls.push(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=${id}&key=${apiKey}`);

    for (var url of urls) { //This for loop will stop in each url to complete its fetch
        let resp = await fetch(url)
        let data = await resp.json()
        console.log(data)
    }
    return 'Good Anakin goooood'
} 

foo()
.then(msg => console.log(msg))
.catch(e => console.log(e)) //If some Error has been thrown or some fetch was rejected.
```